# Zend Soap Server with wsdl - 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, soap, wsdl

I'm working on a project with ZF in windows environment (using wamp) trying to develop a web service (wsdl definition) with the Soap library of Zend.

Everything works as expected at localhost, the URI `http://localhost/mySite/webService/Server.php?wsdl` returns a good definition of the service and it can be consumed. But the same using an IP like, let's say `http://192.168.1.20/mySite/webService/Server.php?wsdl` doesn't seem to be available. I get the error:

`Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /mySite/webService/Server.php on this server.`

I did the test using `http://192.168.0.20/mySite/public/` and it works fine. I get the standard "Welcome to the Zend Framework!" because I haven't changed it yet (it even works using my public IP). In the same project I have some controllers/actions and they fail the same way.

I think the problem could be related with the httpd.conf file, but I don't really know how to handle it. Or maybe the .htaccess on this project?

Has somebody a clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try  without cache in your client:

```
$options['cache_wsdl'] = WSDL_CACHE_NONE:
$uri = http://192.168.1.20/mySite/webService/Server.php?wsdl;
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client($uri, $options);
```

Comment: My client is actually an Android App. Anyway I get the 403 Forbidden error writing the URI in the browser and I should get the wsdl file like at localhost. Using the localhost URI in the browser works fine.